# How can I use application/vnd.ms-excel with non-Latin languages?

Tags: javascript, html

In my app I'm using the below code to export the `tblData` info into Excel, and it works correctly as long as the content is in English.

```js
function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'; // or `application/vnd.ms-excel`
    var input = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tableSelect = document.createElement("table");
    tableSelect = input.cloneNode(true)
    const thead = document.createElement("thead");
    thead.innerHTML =`
   <tr><th>Name</th><th>Skills</th></tr>
    `
    tableSelect.prepend(thead)

    var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.xlsx':'excel_data.xlsx';
    
    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;
    
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
}
```

The output is:

[image]

How can I fix it so the non-Latin words (Arabic in case) appear correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Add `<meta charset='utf-8'>` to the source HTML code.

It's even not necessary to add "html", "head", etc.

This worked for cyrillic; hope your case suits, too.